# Accept a list of rules through user input

Tags: python, string, list

This is code I wrote so far.
The function takes a single character and a set of rules as a list.

```
def applyRules(char, rules):
    ... # some code here
    return result

char = input("What characther do you want to put?")
rules = input("Put your rule")
```

I want the user to input some space separated rules that I convert to a list of rules and pass to my function. This is what I tried.

```
inst = applyRules(char, [rules])
print(inst)
```

For example, when I run it through terminal, This is how I input:

```
"What characther do you want to put?" a
"Put your rule" a:b b:c
```

It looks like it is not working. How users are supposed to input a list rules through the terminal?

Comment: This is rather unclear...

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Edited the question for clarity (since I know exactly what OP is asking - a followup of a previous question). Let me know how it is now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The function takes a single character and a set of rules as a list.

You should understand that `[...]` creates a single element list, I believe (based off your last question) that it's not what you want.

You're looking for `str.split`:

```
In [1429]: rules = input("Input your rules: ")
      ...: 
Input your rules: a:b b:c c:d

In [1430]: rules.split()
Out[1430]: ['a:b', 'b:c', 'c:d']
```

Pass this list to `applyRules`.

Also, just a side note (since you're a beginner), `str.split` is *not* an inplace operation. In this example, I haven't assigned the result back to anything, but you should, if you want to store the list in another variable.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I just got time, so I tried it, but it says **line 5, in applyRules
    char = char.replace(rule_list[0], rule_list[1])
IndexError: list index out of range** with my code in my last question. The input of rules was `a:b b:c c:d`

Comment: @Whitepub Go back to your previous question and use the code I gave you (using a dict).

Comment: It says **line 2, in applyRules mapping = dict(x.split(':') for x in rules)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required**

Comment: @Whitepub Ohk, my bad. There were a couple of typos. I've fixed and tested the function, and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: I do not know why, but it still says same Error

Comment: @Whitepub Please open a new question with your full code, input and error, and link me to it. Thanks.